# PHP Shell can't read certain name files

Tags: php, shell, require

I have a file: `system.php`

```
<?php
function test()1
?>
```

and I include it to a main script `main.php`

```
<?php
require("system.php");
?>
```

I run it with php shell `php\php.exe htdocs\main.php`, and it gives no errors!!

When I rename the included file to `system2.php` and I change `main.php` code to:

```
<?php
require("system2.php");
?>
```

, I run it again `php\php.exe htdocs\main.php` and it gives errors of course.

I have tried everything. Renaming the file, copying all the contents to another file. It seems the only problem is with the name `"system.php"`!. Also, when i request `system.php`, `system2.php` or `main.php` with a browser I always get the error. The scripts are just simple as that.

**Why?**

Comment: `function test()1` is an incorrect syntax anyway, you should get the `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER), expecting '{' in php shell code ....`  anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading it with a relative path, in a directory OTHER than the one you're running the script from.  So if your command line is:

```
c:\a\b\c> php/php.exe scripts/foo.php
```

which simply has

```
<?php require('subdir/script.php');
```

then PHP is going to be trying to include the file using

```
c:\a\b\c\subdir\script.php
```

as the file location.

So, you have

```
c:\a\b\c\> php.exe htdoc\main.php
```

and are doing  `require(system.php)`, which will be causing PHP to look for

```
c:\a\b\c\system.php
```

You probably need `require('htdoc/system.php')` instead, to point at the proper subdirectory, or an absolute full path.